# replace string in HTML doc after page loads

Tags: javascript, regex

Ive a html doc with some markup like:

```
<p>Substance A, a metabolite enhances serotonergic production in neurons [33088927]. Substance B confers neuroprotection [28388366].  &nbsp;</p>
```

After the page loads Id like to find every occurrence in the document where there are square brackets and replace the string with something else, eg [33088927] -> 33088927i.

Using regex101.com Ive put together a function which finds the instances of square brackets:

```
function the_Pubs(){
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        const regex = /\[(.*?)\]/gm;
        let result;
            while((result = regex.exec(document.documentElement.outerHTML)) !== null) {
                if (result.index === regex.lastIndex) {
                        regex.lastIndex++;
                        }

        result.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
            
});
}
})}
```

How can I replace the found instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `String#replace` with a callback function.

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML
            .replace(/\[(.*?)\]/gm, (m, g) => g + "i");
```

Comment: In fact, that would be `.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/gm, (m, g) => g + "i");`. ***eg [33088927] -> 33088927i.***

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Good catch.